# Returning different result when the value is encountered for the 2nd time

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count, conditional-statements

I'm using a kind of search function in VBA. I identify the first time a word is in an column I put a value in the column next to it. But the second time the word is in the column I want another value in the column next to it.

```
Sub Kalender()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cl As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cl In Application.Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)
            If cl.Value = "Agent" Then
                cl.Offset(, -3).Value = "MONDAY"
        End If
        Next cl
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

For now I have this but I need to have a second value for the second time column E contains "Agent".

Comment: What value do you want to enter the 2nd time? Will there be a third time/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a variable like `found_once` which becomes `True` when you find the value "Agent" for the first time.

```
Sub Kalender()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim found_once As Boolean
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cl In Application.Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)
            If cl.Value = "Agent" Then
                If found_once Then
                    cl.Offset(, -3).Value = "MONDAY_again"
                Else
                    cl.Offset(, -3).Value = "MONDAY"
                    found_once = True
                End If
            End If
        Next cl
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you need to keep the count of occurrences, you can use a variable like `found_cases`:

```
Sub Kalender2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim found_cases As Byte
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cl In Application.Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)
            If cl.Value = "Agent" Then
                cl.Offset(, -3).Value = "MONDAY " & found_cases + 1
                found_cases = found_cases + 1
            End If
        Next cl
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```